# I want to convert English Text to Udru in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to convert English like this :

Black = بلیک
Blue = بلیو

Cant found this on internet

Answer (score 0):

You are translating words. Therefore you need a translation-mechanism.

You can either use existing APIs, for example the [Google translator](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) or you have to write your own dictionary and create Key-Value-pairs for the words:

[Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Example code:

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dictionary.Add("Black", "بلیک")
dictionary.Add("Blue", "بلیو")
```